# Fast gradient sign method with keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm currently working on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01474v2)
. To implement the *Fast gradient sign method* with a heteroscedastic neural network.

If we define the loss function as `l(\theta,x,y)` where `x` is the feature, `y` the label and `\theta` the parameters.
Instead of minimizing `l(\theta,x,y)`, the goal is to minimize `l(\theta,x,y)+l(\theta,x',y)` where

`x'=x+\eps*\sign(\nabla_x l(\theta,x,y))`

Here my attempt(without any success):

```
def customLoss(x):
    def neg_log_likelihood(y_true, y_pred):

        def neg_log(y_t,y_p):
            inter=(y_p[...,0,None]-y_t)/K.clip(y_p[...,1,None],K.epsilon(),None)
            val=K.log(K.clip(K.square(y_p[...,1,None]),K.epsilon(),None))+K.square(inter)
            return val

        val=neg_log(y_true,y_pred)

        deriv=K.gradients(val,x)
        xb=x+0.01*K.sign(deriv)
        out=model.predict(xb)
        valb=neg_log(y_true,out)

        return K.mean(val+valb,axis=-1)
    return neg_log_likelihood
```

The calling of this loss function is then

```
model.compile(loss=customLoss(model.inputs),...)
```

Do you have any ideas how can I implement this?

Comment: Why did you not succeed?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible to use `model.predict` within the loss function (it would break backpropagation, right?). You could maybe try to define a Lambda layer in which you compute `out`, and then pass this tensor to the loss function (like you do with `x`).

Comment: Hi Charles. I have moved your solution into a separate answer, as that's how SO works (rather than treating it like a forum post). It makes it more likely that those who come after you searching for a solution to a similar problem will find it.

Comment: Thank's! 
I couldn't answer to myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct loss function is:

```
def customLoss(x):
    def neg_log_likelihood(y_true, y_pred):

        def neg_log(y_t,y_p):
            inter=(y_p[...,0,None]-y_t)/K.clip(y_p[...,1,None],K.epsilon(),None)
            val=K.log(K.clip(K.square(y_p[...,1,None]),K.epsilon(),None))+K.square(inter)
            return val

        val=neg_log(y_true,y_pred)

        deriv=K.gradients(val,x)
        xb=x+0.01*K.sign(deriv)
        out=model(xb)
        valb=neg_log(y_true,out)

        return K.mean(val+valb,axis=-1)
    return neg_log_likelihood
```

The difference is that `model(xb)` returns a tensor while `model.predict(xb)` doesn't.